# Don't collapse comments on much answered questions in review

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, review-queues, comments

Comments are usually collapsed when a question has many answers. When the question or one of the answers comes up in review, the (zero-vote) comments are still collapsed. This doesn't make sense.

Example:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Clarification:

I still want comments to collapse when there are too many of them. The 5 comment threshold seems fine here, but it could also be increased.

Comment: This is actually a very good idea. When reviewing, you want all the pertinent information available. There's no point in hiding the comments in review.

Comment: I occasionally leave comments like "This code-only answer is an exact duplicate of [this other answer with some explanation](some other answer).", expecting reviewers to see them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, it doesn't make sense to use logic on a review page that's made for a question page with 30+ answers. Fixed in the next build, thanks for pointing it out.